# jQuery Nested Droppables

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have a nested set of jQuery droppables...one outer droppable that encompasses most of the page and an a set of nested inner droppables on the page. The functionality I want is:

- If a draggable is dropped outside of any of the inner droppables it should be accepted by the outer droppable.
- If a draggable is dropped onto any of the inner droppables it should NOT be accepted by the outer droppable, regardless of whether the inner droppable accepts the draggable.

So that would be easy if I could guarantee 1+ inner droppables would accept the draggable, because the greedy attribute would make sure it would only get triggered once. Unfortunately the majority of the time the inner droppable will also reject the draggable, meaning the greedy option doesn't really help.

Summary: The basic functionality is a set of valid/invalid inner droppables to accept the draggable, but when you toss the draggable outside any of the draggables it gets destroyed by the outer droppable.

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: [greedy](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-greedy)! That was the answer to my question, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to do this you can't use the built-in `accept` option because that will not trigger the `drop` event for the current droppable if the draggable is not accepter, and will therefor propagate into the parent droppable.

So the best way is to implement your own accept check, which is fairly simple:

```
$('#foo').droppable({
    drop: function(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
});

var accepted = '#red';
$('#bar').droppable({
    greedy: true,
    drop: function(e,ui){
        if (!$(ui.draggable).is(accepted)) {
            return false;
        }
        console.log(e.target);
    }
});
```

You can see how the above works on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/pPs34/).

Comment: it doesn't sound like the problem is "only certain elements go in certain places" so the `.is(accepted)` doesn't make sense to me. It sounds to me like greedy is the place to go - but if it doesn't work I am a bit stumped. I've worked plenty with droppable, but never in a nested situation.

Comment: @JohnO, if you take some time to debug it you'll notice that it will behave just as I explained. The event will propagate if the element is not accepted, even if `greedy` is used, this is because it doesn't fire the `drop` event at all for that droppable.